# Prototype of poker software in C, problems with the function to find out Straights

Tags: c, arrays, function, poker

I'm going crazy.
I'm writing a source that selects 5 poker cards from a shuffled deck and recognizes if there is a couple, double couple, tris and so on. However, the functions that deals with finding a Straight is giving me a hard time. I had to rewrite this because i haven't considered before the fact that the Ace can value 1 as well as 11. This is the source:

```
int hasStraight(const int wFirstFace[],int size)
{
    int *firstfacePtr,i,j;
    firstfacePtr=wFirstFace;

    for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=size-2;j++)
        {
            if (firstfacePtr[j]!=firstfacePtr[j+1]-1 && i==0)
                break;
            else if (firstfacePtr[j]!=firstfacePtr[j+1]-1 && i==1)
                return 0;
            else if (j==3 &&firstfacePtr[j]==firstfacePtr[j+1]-1)
                printf("Scala!\n");
                return 1;
        }
        if (firstfacePtr[0]==0)
            firstfacePtr[0]=13;
            bubble(firstfacePtr,size); /*bubble goes through an array 
                                         and put it in ascending order*/
    }

}
```

Notes: `wFirstFace` is an array containing 5 integers; size is an integer, and it's equal to 5.
I have tried to declare `wFirstFace={0,1,2,3,4}` in order to check if the code worked or not.
Then, the internal 'for' cycle ends after one cycle, and the function returns a 0 and I don't even know why or where.
Where did I make a mistake in this messy source code?

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger: you aren't going to get very far without it anyway.

Comment: Did you retype this here? Please copy and paste when possible. Looks like you're missing braces on that last "else if". Otherwise, return 1 will always happen.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of braces mismatch I could see.

1 - This will always `return 1;`. Do you want to put a `{` `}` for the last `else if`?

```
    for(j=0;j<=size-2;j++)
    {
        if (firstfacePtr[j]!=firstfacePtr[j+1]-1 && i==0)
            break;
        else if (firstfacePtr[j]!=firstfacePtr[j+1]-1 && i==1)
            return 0;
        else if (j==3 &&firstfacePtr[j]==firstfacePtr[j+1]-1)
            printf("Scala!\n");
            return 1;
    }
```

2 - Do you want the `bubble()` to execute for all the iterations of `for(i=` loop? or only when `if (firstfacePtr[0]==0)` is true?

```
    if (firstfacePtr[0]==0)
        firstfacePtr[0]=13;
        bubble(firstfacePtr,size); /*bubble goes through an array and put it in ascending order*/
```

Comment: @user1068051 If you find the above answer useful and information and helped you solve your problem, please confirm so by clicking the tick mark next to it. Thanks!